# How to use MediaQuery.of(context).size without rebuilding?

Tags: flutter, dart

Because there is still not support for multiple screens (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30701) I need to find a way to build application based on screen size.

I need to build different widgets based on screen size, before building MaterialApp.
Is there a way to check the screen size and not to rebuild the app ?

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool isDualScreen =
        MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height > MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;

    if (isDualScreen) {
      return const DualScreen();
    }

    return const MainAppWidget();
  }
}

class MainAppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainAppWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class DualScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DualScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                child: Container()),
          ),
          const Expanded(
            child: MainAppWidget(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on Ubuntu 23.10 6.5.0-13-generic, locale
    en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine VS Code version.
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

[image]

Comment: Check out this summary by Pixeltoast on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/

Comment: I think GetX package offers size without context, you may want to check it . Using is very simple => Get.height ....

Comment: You could probably get help from this tutorial on how to use Media Query https://youtu.be/SC0TZMl_YC8

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a way to get the screen size without rebuilding when it changes, you can use [WidgetsBinding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding-mixin.html):

```
Size screenSize = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize;
double width = screenSize.width;
double height = screenSize.height;
```

You could rewrite your MyApp widget like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late bool isDualScreen;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final Size screenSize = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize /
        WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio;
    isDualScreen = screenSize.height > screenSize.width;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isDualScreen) {
      return const DualScreen();
    }
    return const MainAppWidget();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For that I recommend using getx here is an example:

GetMaterialApp -> SwitchScreen -> [DualScreen || MainAppWidget]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: SwitchScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SwitchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SwitchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Get.height > Get.width ? const DualScreen() : const MainAppWidget();
  }
}

class MainAppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainAppWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(body: Text("Home page"));
  }
}

class DualScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DualScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                child: Container()),
          ),
          const Expanded(
            child: MainAppWidget(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if no want use GETX you can create a sinlgeton for take only the first size

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final WinDual winDual = WinDual(context);
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: SwitchScreen(),
    );
  }
}

///Singleton class to check if the device is dual screen or not
///
class WinDual {
  static WinDual? _appData;

  factory WinDual(BuildContext context) {
    _appData ??= WinDual._internal(context);
    return _appData!;
  }
  bool isDual = false;
  late BuildContext context;

  WinDual._internal(BuildContext context) {
    isDual =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  }
}

class SwitchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SwitchScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ///invoke the WinDual class to check if the device is dual screen or not
    ///it only looks at the size the first time it is invoked
    return WinDual(context).isDual ? const DualScreen() : const MainAppWidget();
  }
}

class MainAppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainAppWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(body: Text("Home page"));
  }
}

class DualScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DualScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                child: Container()),
          ),
          const Expanded(
            child: MainAppWidget(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```